# Difference between Arena::CreateMessage and Arena::CreateMaybeMessage

Tags: protocol-buffers, protocols, protobuf-c

When I using Protocol Buffer with Arena, what is the difference between those 2 functions

```
google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMaybeMessage<LPD::MyObj>();
```

And

```
google::protobuf::Arena::CreateMessage<LPD::MyObj>();
```